# How to return number of arguments of a list of tuples?

Tags: c#, list, generics, tuples

I have a tuple with several arguments and intend to return the number of arguments in it, but it starts with a list.

The list is as it follows:

```
public List<(DateTime cardate, string brand)> getCars()
        {

        var list = new List<(DateTime cardate, string brand)>();
        list.Add(somedate, "some brand");
        list.Add(somedate2, "some brand2");
        return list;
    }
```

I tried to use the `.GetGenericArguments` method that exists in tuples, but since this is a list it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by arguments of a list? You are using one type argument for the list. Do you want to know the number of values in the tuple definition?

Comment: You want to do this based on the list/returned object? `list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetGenericArguments().Length` or you want to do it from an individual item? `((ITuple)list[0]).Length`. Question is kind of unclear though....

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 is it possible to obtain the naming of the tuple as well, such as "cardate" and "brand" but on a different method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding an extra pair of parentheses to your code so that it reads:

```
List<(DateTime cardate, string brand)> getCars()
{
    var list = new List<(DateTime cardate, string brand)>();
    list.Add((DateTime.Now, "some brand"));
    list.Add((DateTime.UtcNow, "some brand2"));
    return list;
}
```

With this slight adjustment, the `Type` of `arg` can be reflected and the generic arguments counted.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Title = "Detect Tuple";
    foreach (var arg in getCars()) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg.GetType().Name);
        Console.WriteLine($"{arg.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Count()} generic arguments." );
        Console.WriteLine($"{arg.cardate} {arg.brand}");
    }
}
```

[image: debug output]

---

**Reflect the `getCars()` method info**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodInfo methodInfoGetCars = 
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .SelectMany(_=>_.GetMethods())
            .FirstOrDefault(_=>_.Name.Equals(nameof(getCars)));

        if(methodInfoGetCars != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The method itself returns one argument, the Tuple.");
            Console.WriteLine($"\t{methodInfoGetCars.ReturnType}");
            Console.WriteLine($"\t{methodInfoGetCars.ReturnType.GetGenericArguments().Count()} generic arguments. {Environment.NewLine}");

            Console.WriteLine("Enumerating the argument count of the tuple:");
            var countOfTupleArgs = 
                methodInfoGetCars
                    .ReturnType.GetGenericArguments()[0]
                    .GetGenericArguments().Count();
            Console.WriteLine($"\tThere are {countOfTupleArgs} indirect generic arguments. {Environment.NewLine}");
        }
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

[image: debug output]

Comment: Could also cast the objects to `ITuple` and get the `Length` property. That said, I believe OP wants to know this *without* iterating over the list

Comment: Thans this is what I was looking for. But is it possible to return it without an instance? Just by consulting the method properties for example?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thanks, indeed, I can do this by calling the arg[0] when var arg = getCars(), but I'd rather get the arguments without instantiating the list of cars, and just by the method getCars() properties.

Comment: @anotherJ.Doe I _want_ to say yes you can reflect the method and determine this without an instance. But I'm going to attempt it before I commit to that answer:)

Comment: I've added the method reflection to the answer. The tricky thing seems to be that the return type has one generic argument that is a tuple holding two generic arguments.