# Is it possible to read a Tuple item value that is inside a list that is an argument inside a generic method

Tags: c#, list, generics, tuples

I have a list of Tuples that works very well and I can easily read it with list[index].ItemX as common.
But I have a problem when the list is an argument in a generic method.

For example:

```
  //Tuples list creation
        public List<(double anumber, string astring)> ListOfTuples()
        {
            var list = new List<(double anumber, string astring)>();
            list.Add((123.4, "stringtext"));
            return list;
        }
```

The above generates a list I can easily manipulate, unless it is an argument in a generic as below:

```
//Generic list reader where I'm trying to load Item1, Item2.. or even better, the naming "anumber" and "astring"
    public void SplitList<T>(List<T> readlist)
    {
        string msg = "";
        msg += readlist[0].ToString() + "\n" + "\n";
        msg += readlist[0].GetType().GetField("Item1") + "\n" + "\n";
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
```

The furthest I could get was to the field Item1 name, but I cannot call his value.
I also found some information that provides the length of the parameters here:
[How to return number of arguments of a list of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75715075/how-to-return-number-of-arguments-of-a-list-of-tuples)

```
readlist.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetGenericArguments().Length
```

I plan to use call these 2 methods like this:

```
SplitList<(double, string)>(ListOfTuples());
```

But I'd like that it splites Item1 (the double) and Item2 (the string)
Is such possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few solutions here that completely avoid the need for reflection.

**Firstly**, If you are sure your type `T` will be a tuple of some sort, you could constrain your type `T` to implement the [`ITuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.ituple) interface:

> Defines a general-purpose Tuple implementation that allows access to Tuple instance members without knowing the underlying Tuple type.

Then your `SplitList()` would be written as follows:

```
public void SplitList<T>(List<T> readlist) where T : ITuple
{
    var item = readlist[0];
    var item1 = item.Length > 0 ? item[0] : null;
    var item2 = item.Length > 1 ? item[1] : null;

    string msg = "";
    msg += item.ToString() + "\n" + "\n";
    if (item1 != null)
        msg += item1 + "\n" + "\n";
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

Both the `Tuple` and `ValueTuple` types implement this interface.

**Secondly**, if you are not sure that the type `T` will be a tuple, you can test for the `ITuple` interface as required:

```
public void SplitList<T>(List<T> readlist)
{
    var item = readlist[0];
    var tuple = item as ITuple;
    var item1 = tuple?.Length > 0 ? tuple[0] : null;
    var item2 = tuple?.Length > 1 ? tuple[1] : null;

    string msg = "";
    msg += item.ToString() + "\n" + "\n";
    if (item1 != null)
        msg += item1 + "\n" + "\n";
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

If you don't know how large the tuple might be, you could additionally introduce an extension method that tries to extract a tuple's values as an `object? []` array, then loop through the array using the tuple's [`Length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.ituple.length) property:

```
public static class TupleExtensions
{
    public static bool TryGetTupleItems<T>(this T? possibleTuple, [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.NotNullWhen(returnValue: true)] out object? []? items)
    {
        if (!(possibleTuple is ITuple tuple))
        {
            items = null;
            return false;
        }
        items = new object[tuple.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < tuple.Length; i++)
        {
            items[i] = tuple[i];
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then do:

```
public void SplitList<T>(List<T> readlist)
{
    var item = readlist[0];

    string msg = "";
    msg += item?.ToString() + "\n" + "\n";
    if (item.TryGetTupleItems(out var items))
        foreach (var value in items)
            msg += value + "\n" + "\n";
    
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

**Finally**, if you are sure that your type `T` will be a [`ValueTuple<T1, T2>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2) for some `T1` and `T2`, you could declare your `SplitList()` method as having **two** generic arguments:

```
public void SplitList<T1, T2>(List<(T1, T2)> readlist) 
{
    var item = readlist[0];
    var item1 = item.Item1;
    var item2 = item.Item2;

    string msg = "";
    msg += item.ToString() + "\n" + "\n";
    if (item1 != null)
        msg += item1 + "\n" + "\n";
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

No matter which you chose, C#'s [type inferencing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods) will infer the correct generic arguments, so you can call `SplitList` as follows:

```
SplitList(ListOfTuples());
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oKdutJ).

Comment: What I don't like about this answer is that it presumes that I will use Tuple all the time.. I have to specify it in SplitList method.. For that there's no point in using a generic list..  Besides I know the Tuple type with readlist[0].GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetGenericArguments()

Comment: @CésarAmorim - Your question wasn't entirely clear about what your constraints, but the second option of testing for the `ITuple` interface would seem to meet your needs.

Comment: I cannot guarantee Tuple will always have 2 items, sometimes it might have 3, sometimes it can be a KeyValue dictionary. This might be a step further of the Generics intention, but since I can read the Tuple Items with readlist[0].GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetGenericArguments(), there must be a way to get their values as well.

Comment: `ITuple` has a property `Length` that tells you the number of items.  But if you have a dictionary then none of this code is relevant.  Also dictionaries don't have an `Item1` property.

Comment: Indeed, the point is to have a multipurpose generic method that can reach the names inside. But thanks. Edit: The second method attempt you provided works in fact. Thanks

Comment: I made a if condition that checks if we have a ValueTuple and it goes in very well. It also checks for KeyValuePair as well, but I don't have a function IKeyValuePair that can be assigned as that type of element.  Would you know how to read a Key and Value name in case the List is of KeyValue pairs?

Comment: @CésarAmorim - The format for questions on stack overflow is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735), so I'd suggest you ask a second question.  But is this what you want?  [How to get value from a KeyValuePair<> with unknown type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58115255).